# Eigenvalue is giving me a null eigenvector, which contradicts its very definition

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

I'm computing the eigenvectors of an eigenvalue as part of the solution to this problem:

$$(D^2 - I_2 \lambda_+) v_+ = 0$$ ,

where the eigenvalue is $\lambda_+ = w^2$ and $D^2$ is an operator given by
$D^2 = \begin{pmatrix}-w^2
 &0 \\ 0
 & -w^2
\end{pmatrix} $

Plugging it in the first equation we get to

$$\left \{ \begin{pmatrix}-w^2
 &0 \\ -0
 & -w^2 \end{pmatrix} -
\begin{pmatrix}1
 &0 \\ 0
 & 1 \end{pmatrix}w^2 \right \}
 \begin{pmatrix} 
v_1 \\ v_2
\end{pmatrix}
= 0$$

which yields $-2w^2v_1 = 0$ and $-2w^2 v_2 = 0$, and thus the eigenvector is $v_+ = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $

If I carry out the other eigenvalue $\lambda_- = -w^2$ it doesn't yield anything since there'll be a $\begin{pmatrix}0
 &0 \\ 0
 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ matrix multiplying the eigenvector, $v_-$, matrix.

> To give a little context, this is part of an attempt to find the
>   eigenvectors of the matrices of two operators $D \equiv \frac{d}{dt}$
>   and $D^2 \equiv \frac{d^2}{dt^2}$ in a vector space of basis
>   $\mathbf{e} = \left \{ \cos(wt), \sin(wt)\right \}$
>
> In such vector space these operators are represented in matrix form as
>
> $$D =  \begin{pmatrix} 0  &w \\ -w & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \ \  D^2 = \begin{pmatrix} -w^2  &0 \\ 0 & -w^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Note: I did find the eigenvectors for $D$, but $D^2$ just won't come out.

Comment: Nevermind, I've already found my mistake. It turns out I forgot a minus sign while evaluating the eigenvalue for $D^2$. Thanks anyway.

Comment: $w^2$ is not an eigenvalue of $D^2$ (as written). Also, what's wrong with $\begin{pmatrix}0
 &0 \\ 0
 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$? (try calculating the eigenvectors for $I_2$)

Comment: I see that now, I forgot a minus sign while evaluating the determinant, it turns out, $\mathbb{det}(D^2-I \lambda)=(-w^2-\lambda)^2=0$

Answer (score 2):

Actually, $w^2$ is simply *not* an eigenvalue for $D^2$, since $\mathbb{det}(D^2-w^2 I)=4w^4$, which is not zero, provided that $w \neq 0$.

Since $D^2=-w^2 I$, so $D^2 v = -w^2 I v = -w^2 v$, and it is easy to see that it's only eigenvalue is $-w^2$ and any vector is an eigenvector.

Comment: So, the eigenvector is just any vector? Like, any random vector whatsoever? The basis imposes no restrictions? Also, there is only one eigenvector, right?

Comment: @chiliandseabass at least over reals, there is always an infinite number of eigenvectors once a single one is found, since if $Ax=\lambda x$, then $A(kx) = k(Ax) = k(\lambda x) = \lambda (kx)$. Yes, for $D^2$, any non-zero vector would be an eigenvector. This is true for all operators of the form $A=kI$, since $Ax=(kI)x = kx$, and the eigenvalue is $k$ ($k=-w^2$ for your case).

Comment: @chiliandseabass There’s never “only one eigenvector” (over $\mathbb R$, anyway) since any non-zero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector of the same eigenvalue. In this case, _every_ vector is an eigenvector of $-w^2$, so the eigenspace will be two-dimensional.